# How to get the ISRC code for a music track with a Gracenote API query

Tags: gracenote

I have tried with the following query which includes the LINK parameter which I found in the Gracenote forum. However the ISRC code is not returned:

```
       <QUERIES>
            <AUTH>
                <CLIENT>xxx</CLIENT>
                <USER>xxx</USER>
            </AUTH>
            <QUERY CMD="ALBUM_SEARCH">
                <TEXT TYPE="ARTIST">Rihanna</TEXT><TEXT TYPE="TRACK_TITLE">Man Down</TEXT><TEXT TYPE="ALBUM_TITLE">Loud</TEXT><OPTION>
                  <PARAMETER>SELECT_EXTENDED</PARAMETER>
                  <VALUE>COVER,REVIEW,ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY,ARTIST_IMAGE,ARTIST_OET,MOOD,TEMPO,LINK</VALUE>
              </OPTION><OPTION>
                  <PARAMETER>SELECT_DETAIL</PARAMETER>
                  <VALUE>GENRE:3LEVEL,MOOD:2LEVEL,TEMPO:3LEVEL,ARTIST_ORIGIN:4LEVEL,ARTIST_ERA:2LEVEL,ARTIST_TYPE:2LEVEL</VALUE>
              </OPTION><OPTION>
                  <PARAMETER>COVER_SIZE</PARAMETER>
                  <VALUE>MEDIUM</VALUE>
              </OPTION>
            </QUERY>
        </QUERIES>
```